# Using PHP file_get_contents with xml

Tags: php, xml, xampp, file-get-contents

I'm not sure if it is my XAMPP setup which is causing this issue however i have currently got a php page creating sample XML data as seen below:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<product/>');
$xml->addChild("price", "US DOLLARS");
$xml->addChild("test","123123");
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

this renders the XML onscreen perfectly. However when i come to read the page using the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("api.xml");
echo $xml->price;
```

so i have checked the file firstly using file_get_contents("xml.php");

but it returns the PHP code rather then the output of the code.
I have resolved this by using the xml.php to write a file called feed.xml which works fine but was just wondering why the file_get_contents("xml.php"); returned the code rather then the parsed output. Have i simply used the wrong method to check the file contents or is this a setup issue with xampp?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because `file_get_contents` - ["_Reads entire file into a string_"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). It doesn't run the PHP then include the response.

Comment: would i be better using CURL? or just run the script via a cron to generate the XML every 15 minutes?

Comment: Yeah, those are both options that should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you do you want to write this as an answer so i can tick as correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is:

> ...the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string.

It doesn't run the PHP then include the response. To do that you'd have to either generate the xml and use `file_get_contents` to get the xml file or use PHP's [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) function (as you suggested).

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify full url with http:// otherwise file_get_contents read local file